# How can I change the Universal Login logo on auth0 dashboard?

Tags: auth0

I'm currently stuck on the auth0 Universal Login page.
I want to change the logo by [given an url](https://d2qcgv1x1k2it7.cloudfront.net/icons/travel-logo-white-bg.png) but it keep telling me that the url is not valid.

I don't know what to do anymore because the exact same url is valid for the Application logo.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSi4o.png)

Comment: Hi! It's better for stack overflow to include the screenshots directly here, instead in Imgur and then linking

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you might get that error if you have an whitespace before or after the link too. Can you check whether or not you have that white space in there? maybe that's it